# LINQ query grab a datetime and stringify it or return empty string if its the default value of a datetime

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I want to query AsOf datetime from the table and stringify the datetime. If the datetime is the default value it should be an empty string.

I tried this code:

```cs
var dtF = _dbcontext.UpStart_Repayments
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.AsOf)
            .Select(x => x.AsOf.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty)
            .First();
```

But I get this error message:

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The Issue is the code line

```cs
.DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty)
```

I got it to work by writing it this way, but is there a better way?

```cs
var dd1 = _dbcontext.UpStart_Repayments
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.AsOf)
        .Select(x => x.AsOf)
        .Take(1)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        .DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty)
        .First();
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore {7.0.10}  and Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Use the null conditional operator instead of `DefaultIfEmpty`: `Select(x => x.ToString("yyy-MM-dd") ?? String.Empty)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` has different meaning - it should return at least one record if there are no records in main query.

For your case you should use `Conditional` operator on the client side, because `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` is not translatable to the SQL.

```cs
var dateReturned = _dbcontext.UpStart_Repayments
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.AsOf)
    .Select(x => x.AsOf)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var dtF = dateReturned != null ? dateReturned.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty;
```

Or using null propagating operator, thanks @NetMage for reminding:

```cs
var dtF = _dbcontext.UpStart_Repayments
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.AsOf)
    .Select(x => x.AsOf)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Don't forget you can do `dateReturned?.ToString("yyy-MM-dd") ?? String.Empty` as well.